# Indentation of footnotes depending on number of digits in footnote marks on the same page

Tags: footnotes, indentation, conditionals, ifthenelse

I wanted to adjust the left indentation of footnotes depending on the number of digits of the footnote mark. Thus, footnotes with one digit are aligned a the length of single \parindent (which is set at 4mm) from the left margin: while footnotes with two or three digits (let's not assume there will be more) are aligned 8 mm from the left (= 2*\parindent). I managed to do so with the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{4mm}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,footnote}
    \VerbatimFootnotes% I created the code in a file which used this command, but for some reason it doesn't work without it.
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
        \ifthenelse{\value{footnote}>9}{%
            \parindent 12mm%
            \noindent
            \@hangfrom{%
                \hb@xt@ 8mm{\@thefnmark}#1%
            }%
        }{%
            \parindent 8mm%
            \noindent
            \@hangfrom{%
                \hb@xt@ 4mm{\@thefnmark}#1%
            }%
        }%
    }
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
A word, phrase, or sentence that needs to be commented on.\footnote{\blindtext}
\setcounter{footnote}{15}
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext\par\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Then I had a second problem: on a page that has any one- and two-digit footnotes, I do not want this difference. There, the double indentation/margin should be used for one-digit footnote marks as well. I figure that it should be enough to make the indentation dependent on whether footnote 10 appears on the page or not. Is there a way to add such a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

The original answer used `\thepage` which is not reliable. I've updated this answer to use `\oddpage@page` from the `ifoddpage` package. See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473903/indentation-of-footnotes-depending-on-number-of-digits-in-footnote-marks-on-the).

---

Here's an attempt at doing this. It uses the `aux` file and needs to be compiled at least twice and sometimes three times (depending on page breaks) to ensure indents are correct.

I've also used the `footmisc` package which gives an inbuilt interface for hanging footnotes like you want.

It writes the width of the footnote indent to the `aux` file in a page specific skip at each footnote. Then uses the last of these on each page (which will be the maximum skip) to set the indent on the second pass.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparindent}{4mm}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}
  {\bgroup
   \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
     \ifdim\footnotemargin>0pt
       \hb@xt@\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}%
     \else
       \@makefnmark
     \fi
   }}
  {\bgroup
   \checkoddpage
   \ifcslength{@\thepage @max@footnotemargin}
     {\footnotemargin \csname @\oddpage@page @max@footnotemargin\endcsname}
     {}%
   \immediate\write\@auxout{%
     \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\newskip
       \noexpand\csname @\oddpage@page @max@footnotemargin\endcsname}%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{footnote}}{9}
     {\immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \global\noexpand\csname @\oddpage@page @max@footnotemargin\endcsname 8mm}}
     {\immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \global\noexpand\csname @\oddpage@page @max@footnotemargin\endcsname 4mm}}%
   % remove superscript footnote mark
   \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
     \ifdim\footnotemargin>0pt
       \hb@xt@\footnotemargin{\hbox{\normalfont \@thefnmark}\hss}%
     \else
       \hbox{\normalfont \@thefnmark}%
     \fi
   }}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text.\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}
Filler text.\footnote{\lipsum*[2]\par\lipsum*[2]}
\clearpage
\null\vfill
Filler text.\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}
\setcounter{footnote}{9}
Filler text.\footnote{\lipsum*[2]\par\lipsum*[2]}
\end{document}
```

### Page 1 output

[image: page 1]

### Page 2 output

[image: page 2]

Comment: Very nice indeed!